# SQL Server 2012 Case when not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, case

I have this Case in my select statement , but it only shows the a.InsertDate even if the date is less than the b.InsertDate. A4 table is part of the table I am making a relationship to.

```
(select top 1 case when a.InsertDate > b.InsertDate then a.InsertDate else b.InsertDate end
        from tblAccount aa
        inner join tblContact c on aa.AccountID = c.AccountID
        inner join tblContactNote b on c.ContactID = b.ContactID
        inner join tblAccountNote a on aa.AccountID = a.AccountID
        where aa.AccountID = a4.AccountID and not a.Note like 'Account Assigned to%'
        order by a.InsertDate desc) [LastestDay]
```

Comment: You're missing an "as [columnname]" at the end.  Other than that it looks ok.

Comment: so what values are actually in those `InsertDate` fields? are they actual date/datetime fields? if they're just varchar, and you're NOT storing your date strings in most-significant-first ordering, then you get string comparisons, and string comparison rules apply, not date comparison rules.

Comment: SQL `CASE` expressions work fine in SQL Server 2012.  If you get different answers than you expect then either your query is broken some other way, or your data are in some way not what you think they are.

Comment: it's comparing datetime data type

Comment: i made a generic name for stackoverflow purposes called [LastestDay]

Comment: Read on [how to post a T-SQL question on forums/StackOverflow](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). We need sample data, the output you get and the output you expect to be able to help you properly.

Comment: You claim "it only shows the a.InsertDate even if the date is greater than the b.InsertDate". `when a.InsertDate > b.InsertDate then a.InsertDate` looks like it _should_ return `a.InsertDate` if it is greater.

Comment: good catch , I met to say even if it's less than. It only displays the a.InsertDate. I am going through the link that TT. provided . It is freaking awesome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inasmuch as `CASE` expressions work fine in SQL Server, and as you assert that the columns you are comparing both have `datetime` type, I'm inclined to think that you are mistaken in claiming that your query "only shows the `a.InsertDate` even if [that] date is [less] than the `b.InsertDate`" (where I take the liberty of interpreting your claim in a manner that makes sense of your surprise).

Since you have presented no data, we can only speculate on how you might have gotten such a mistaken impression.  I observe, however, that you are ordering by `a.InsertDate` (descending) and then selecting the result from the first row.  This will always be the result from the row with the greatest value of `a.InsertDate`.  That row may or may not be the one with the greatest value of `case when a.InsertDate > b.InsertDate then a.InsertDate else b.InsertDate end`.  If what you actually want is the greatest value of the `CASE` expression then your query is wrong.

In that event, I'm not seeing why you want to use a `SELECT TOP` query instead of selecting the `MAX()` value of your case expression:

```
select
  max(case when a.InsertDate > b.InsertDate then a.InsertDate else b.InsertDate end)
from
  tblAccount aa
  inner join tblContact c on aa.AccountID = c.AccountID
  inner join tblContactNote b on c.ContactID = b.ContactID
  inner join tblAccountNote a on aa.AccountID = a.AccountID
where
  aa.AccountID = a4.AccountID
  and not a.Note like 'Account Assigned to%'
```